# Parsing a date in Scala

Tags: scala

Trying to parse a date string, `2020-10-20 19:36:00` using this Scala code.

```
val DATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val date = LocalDate.parse("2020-10-20 19:36:00", DATE_FORMAT).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
```

However when I `println(date)` I get this line `2020-10-20T00:00+02:00[Europe/Stockholm]`
which is only including the date without hours, minutes... What method should I use instead to obtain a ZonedDateTime object containing all information in my date string.

Comment: why is this wrong? This is exactly start of the day in local format. Please write what did you expect and why?

Comment: Should not I be able to call date.getMinute() and get 36 back instead of 0?

Comment: If you want to preserve hours and minutes, don't use atStartOfDay.

Comment: A `LocalDate` has no hours or minutes, just the date. `atStartOfDay()` adds them back in as `00:00`. If you want to preserve the specified hours/minutes use `LocalDateTime.parse(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using this piece of code.

```
    val DATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    val date = ZonedDateTime.parse(x,DATE_FORMAT)
```

I added the ZoneId to the pattern, making it possible to use the ZoneDateTime.parse(...) method